# useState not forcing re-render of react component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, use-effect, use-state

I have a component which a prop `value` which is an object, one of the properties of `value` is `aliases` which is an array of string. I have an add alias button which should add an alias to the object. I am displaying all aliases with `.map` in the component, but when I add an alias the component does not re-render. I can see the `state` updating properly with `react dev-tools` in the browser, but the component does not re-render the updated list. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Accordion from "@components/common/Accordion"
import Alias from "./value-form/Alias"

const ValueItem = props => {
    const { value } = props
     
    /** EXAMPLE VALUE 

                   "id": 1,
                "name": "Primary Descriptor",
                "programmaticName": "Primary_Descriptor",
                "fileTypeDetailId": 9,
                "fileType": "File Type no. 9",
                "standardValue": "Outgoing",
                "isActive": true,
                "aliases": ["Alias 1", "Alias 2", "Alias 3"]
    */


    const dispatch = useDispatch()


    const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(value)
    const [formAliases, setFormAliases ] = useState(value.aliases)

    const addAlias = () => {
        const updatedFormValue = formValue;
        updatedFormValue.aliases.push("");
        setFormValue(updatedFormValue)
        setFormAliases(updatedFormValue.aliases)
    }



    return (
        <Accordion
            key={value.id}
            title={value.name} />
            }
        >
            <div className={styles.valueFormContainer}>

                {formAliases.map((alias) => {
                    return ({alias})
                }
                )}
                <Button handleChange={() => { addAlias()}} buttonLabel="+ Add Alias" buttonTypes={["orange"]} />
            </div>
        </Accordion>)
}

export default ValueItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here

```
 const addAlias = () => {
    const updatedFormValue = formValue;
    updatedFormValue.aliases.push("");
    setFormValue(updatedFormValue)
    setFormAliases(updatedFormValue.aliases)
}
```

you are mutating the exists state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

in your case i'd use

```
setFormValue(prevState=>[...prevState,aliases:[...prevState.aliases,""])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't push new item to the array for updating state. Your `push` will mutate the state directly and that could potentially lead to error prone code. If you would like to push item to array of states, you can make a shallow copy of the state with [`destructuring-assignment`](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment), push to it and finally update the state with the copied array :

```
  const addAlias = () => {
        const updatedFormValue = formValue;
        let copy = [...updatedFormValue.aliases];
        copy.push("");
        setFormValue(updatedFormValue);
        setFormAliases(copy);
    }
```

Comment: There is no destructuring anywhere in your code